# The definition of fuzzy sets using logical and set operators.

Tags: logic, set-theory, predicate-logic, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I wrote this definition of fuzzy sets and fuzzy logic  for a college assignment and was wondering if it is correct:

Let *a* be any ordinary element of the universal superset *U* and *A* be a subset of *U*, and *P(a)* is a membership function, then:

$$\forall a((a \in U \land A \subseteq U) \iff (0 \lt P(a) \le 1 \rightarrow a \in A))$$

This would read "For all element a, a belongs to the superset U and A is a subset of U, then a also belongs to A if, and only if, P(a) is between the interval [0,1)". Is this a correct way to represent the degree of truth elements of a fuzzy logic set can have?

Edit: fixed the proposition.